# How Oracle Database 10g used index?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have table “result”, DDL :

```
CREATE TABLE result
    (id_graduate                    NUMBER NOT NULL,
    id_sml                         NUMBER NOT NULL,
    last_update                    DATE NOT NULL,
    id_kt                          NUMBER NOT NULL,
    value_kt                       NUMBER NOT NULL,
    id_res                         NUMBER NOT NULL)
/
ALTER TABLE result
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_id_res PRIMARY KEY (id_res)
```

And INDEX:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX x_pk_id_res ON result
  (
    id_res                          ASC
  )
  STORAGE   (
    INITIAL     65536
    MINEXTENTS  1
    MAXEXTENTS  2147483645
  )
NOPARALLEL
LOGGING
/
```

When I run SQL #1 query, Oracle used index X_PK_ID_RES

```
select ss.*
from V_JOURNAL ss, result r
where TO_NUMBER(ss.ID_SML||ss.ID_KT||ss.ID_GRADUATE)=r.id_res
```

But, when I run SQL #2 query, Oracle did not use index X_PK_ID_RES, but used ACCESS FULL TABLE result

```
select ss.*,r.* 
from V_JOURNAL ss, result r
where TO_NUMBER(ss.ID_SML||ss.ID_KT||ss.ID_GRADUATE)=r.id_res
```

So, I add new colum id_res2:

```
ALTER TABLE RESULT  ADD (  ID_RES2 NUMBER );
```

And I created the new index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX x_id_res2 ON result
  (
    id_res2                          ASC
  )
  STORAGE   (
    INITIAL     65536
    MINEXTENTS  1
    MAXEXTENTS  2147483645
  )
NOPARALLEL
LOGGING
```

When I run SQL #3 query, Oracle used index X_ID_RES2

```
select ss.* 
from V_JOURNAL ss, result r
where TO_NUMBER(ss.ID_SML||ss.ID_KT||ss.ID_GRADUATE)=r.id_res2
```

And, when I run SQL #4 query, Oracle used index X_ID_RES2 too.

```
select ss.*,r.* 
from V_JOURNAL ss, result r
where TO_NUMBER(ss.ID_SML||ss.ID_KT||ss.ID_GRADUATE)=r.id_res2
```

Why Oracle used index in SQL #4, but did not use in SQL #2 ?

Example V_JOURNAL is view:

```
create or replace view V_JOURNAL as
select count(*) as ID_SML,1 as ID_KT,1 as ID_GRADUATE from dual
```

Explain plan for SQL#1 :
[image: Explain plan for SQL#1]

Explain plan for SQL#2 :
[image: Explain plan for SQL#2]

Explain plan for SQL#3 :
[image: Explain plan for SQL#3]

Explain plan for SQL#4 :
[image: Explain plan for SQL#4]

Pictures produced by SQL Navigator 7.

Comment: Try it also on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You should look at the explain plans for both queries. Is `id_res2` populated? Are your stats up-to-date? Query 2 might be doing a full table scan instead of a full index scan because it knows it has to pull the table data (because of the `r.*`) not just values it can get from the index anyway as it can with queries 1 and 3.

Comment: What you've shown can't be right though; you can't have your `pk_id_res` PK and your `x_pk_id_res` UK on the same `id_res` column. If it is actually the PK and its index that are being used, then `id_res` is implicitly not nullable, while `id_res2` is; which might make a difference to the plan.

Comment: I looked plan there is a difference in the use of the index.

Comment: @AndreKirpitch - if you add the plans to the question (*not* as comments!) someone might be able to say why the index use is different; it's all rather vague at the moment. Also, please don't [cross-post across sites](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/57615/847).

Comment: @AlexPoole I'll post a picture with query plans tomorrow , because I'll be in the office tomorrow

Comment: @AlexPoole I added plans.

Comment: @AndreKirpitch I completely agree on Alex comment regarding Index creation after PK. When I tried the indexes are used properly.

Comment: @realspirituals The index was created automatically after the creation of a primary key

Comment: @AndreKirpitch - if you run the `create table` and `alter table` as you've shown, the `create index` will get `ORA-01408: such column list already indexed`. However the plans show the unique index name being used, so your primary key can't exist. I notice you changed the table definition to make `id_res` `not null`, which would have been implicit from a PK anyway. `id_res2` s nullable though. I still want to know if `id_res2` is populated and if stats are up-to-date.

Comment: @AlexPoole But I tried on another computer with the Oracle Database 10g, Oracle used the index in sql#2.

Comment: @AndreKirpitch - if everything else is identical and you just built these objects in your new instance, then that still leaves stale stats. If you gather stats on your original instance does the behaviour change? I'd probably expect both #2 and #4 to do a full table scan with fresh stats. And gather stats on the second instance and see what, if anything, changes there - I suspect it will also do FTS for both.